# dijit.form.FilteringSelect how to add separator programmatically

Tags: dojo, separator

I am new to Dojo. I am writing up a page which loads the FilteringSelect with a memory store programmatically. Memory store gets the data from a Json service. I want to add separator to FilteringSelect dropdown values but I am not able to find out how to do that. How can I do it it programmatically?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzFPM/3/ I'm not sure if this is helpful to you or not

Comment: Thanks Ravi. This does appear as a separator but it is not separator but a value only. If I go with it then I will need a logic also to make it not selectable value otherwise end user can select it and it will go down further in appalication as value "------"

Comment: Yeah. I checked documentation. I didn't find anything that will give you separator equivalent of HTML select programatically. But I have doubt, why you need this in FilteringSelect, as user gonna type initials and they will get desired filtered options.

Comment: I need this to separate list of country. There are some preferred country which I want to separate out from others. If there is no support for separator then I might go for initial solution shared by you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it´s kind of old, but i was searching for this and came across this question, so this is what i got:
The dojo documentation ( http://bill.dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9#addOption), shows that:

> If value of the option is empty or missing, a separator is created instead.

So, if you use a store to populate the select, the code below should work on dojo 1.10.4:

```
require(["dijit/form/Select",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Select, ObjectStore, Memory){

  var store = new Memory({
    data: [
      { id: "foo", label: "Foo" },
      { id: "bar", label: "Bar" }
    ]
  });

  var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: store });

  var s = new Select({
    store: os
  }, "target");
  s.startup();

  s.on("change", function(){
      console.log("my value: ", this.get("value"))
  })
})
```